# WPF Rotate text

Tags: wpf, rotation

I´m tryng to do something like this:

[image]

I have a List with my own object, in this List I have all the information to draw it, I have a Listbox and every figure is an item of Listbox that I draw in a position of the canvas.

My problem is when I want to draw the Name, becuase I have to rotate the name and to draw it inside of the rectangle of the name, but when I rotate the name I don´t know how to draw it inside de rectangle.

I´m using this datatemplate for my listbox ItemTemplate, I put visibility depending on if I want to draw the image or name.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="templateList">
    <Canvas >
        <WrapPanel 
                  Visibility="{Binding IsStone, Converter={StaticResource converterCheckIsVisibleName}}"
                  Width="{Binding ObjectName.Width}"
                  Height="{Binding ObjectName.Height}">

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectName.Name}" >
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ObjectName.Rotate}" />
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                </TextBlock>
            </WrapPanel>


           <Border BorderThickness="1"  BorderBrush="Black" 
                        Visibility="{Binding IsStone, Converter={StaticResource converterCheckIsVisibleStone}}">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ObjectIMG.PathImagen}" 
                           Height="{Binding ObjectIMG.Height}"
                           Width="{Binding ObjectIMG.Width}"
                           Stretch="Fill" />
                </Border>

            </Canvas>                                        
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your problem is, but it seems as though you just want to rotate some text and put it into a rectangle. The `Rectangle` class does not take a content element, so you can't use that, but you *can* use a simple `Border` element.

One other thing to notice is that you should probably use the `LayoutTransform` which occurs *before* the layout pass, as opposed to the `RenderTransform` which is applied afterwards. See the [FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for more information on this. Try something like this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectName.Name}" >
        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ObjectName.Rotate}" />
        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Comment: @Sheridan Is there a same property in UWP?

Comment: @quangkid, try looking at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/transforms).

Comment: @Sheridan Yes, I'm using this but it doesn't solve my issue. Can you take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507930/uwp-how-to-create-panel-with-rotation